# How to import a view to cakephp default layout

Tags: cakephp

I am new to cakephp...I have a user add form (add.ctp) and would like to display this form in my default layout (default.ctp)

Comment: Which version of CakePhp are you using?

Comment: Then look at the answer below, although this should already be in the default layout (https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/app/View/Layouts/default.ctp#L49)

Answer (score 2):

Aren't Elements the thing you're looking for?

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#elements

Answer (score 0):

In your default layout there should be a line:

```
print $this->fetch('content');
```

If this line is there than cake will automatically include the needed view based on the url and routing.

Comment: thanks for the info..but the default layout will have other resources along with this form(add.ctp).. but doesn't routing just redirects to that page based on the controller and action